# webrtc trun server not working (ice trickle not working in mozilla firefox)

Tags: server, webrtc, nat, stun, turn

I have installed turn server in my **godaddy server**. To see that my turn server is working or not i have used https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/.

ICE Trickle in chrome output:
[Chrome Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY0xA.png)

ICE Trickle in mozilla output (version-58.0.2(64bit)):
[Mozilla output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kl28.png)

**Issues i am facing:**

1.webrtc works only for chrome to chrome(webrtc doesnt work for mozilla to mozilla).

2.mozilla shows "ICE failed add STUN error".

3.why there is different ICE trickle output for both the browsers?

It seems to me that turn server is not working!!
Can anybody help me with these issue i dont know what i am doing wrong. I dont know if its **NAT** problem or godaddy server problem or anything else. Are godaddy servers behind **NAT**?

Configurations i have done:

**Firewall changes:**

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3478 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 3478 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5349 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 5349 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 49152:65535 -j ACCEPT

service iptables save

**Turnserver configuration:**

listening-port=3478

listening-ip=1.2.3.4(example)

external-ip=same as listening ip i.e 1.2.3.4(example)

verbose

fingerprint

realm = mydomain.com

**I am running turn server using these command :**

turnserver -L listening-ip -o -a -f -r mydomain.com

Comment: Is it coturn as your stun and turn?

Comment: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html#centos i have used these site for installation turn server for centos @Herman Fransen

Comment: You use CentOS on your godaddy server?

Comment: yes CentOS version 6 @Herman Fransen

Comment: @CloudDarK : Sorry, I know only Ubuntu

Comment: @CloudDarK : Maybe it is still useful, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909643/coturn-webrtc-issue-on-azure-vm-ubuntu-server-16-04-lts/48926278#48926278)

Comment: No problem mate thnx for replying but do you think is there NAT problem? beacuse there is relay in chrome but not in mozilla (ICE trickle)@Herman Fransen

Comment: I think your Stun / Turn server is not installed right

Comment: How do you check if it is installed correctly? @Herman Fransen

Comment: Trial and error method. I googled a lot, but different resources said different things how to install it correctly. [The website you mention](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice) to test didn't work for me. [Read here in the last part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909643/coturn-webrtc-issue-on-azure-vm-ubuntu-server-16-04-lts/48926278#48926278) how I did the testing.

Comment: It's not clear to me what package you are installing? The site you used talks about different packages: coturn, restund and reTurnServer.

Comment: i have used No. 4 TURN installation on CentOS @HermanFransen

Comment: No. 4 is not clear what package you are installing. You are downloading from `http://turnserver.open-sys.org`. Turnserver is a general thing, you have coturn, restund, reTurnServer, etc. that have an implementation of a Turn Server. Like nginx and apache are implementations of a webserver. I tried to install No. 1 but that didn't work as well. @ClouDarK

Comment: I am not sure but i think it should be these link https://github.com/coturn/rfc5766-turn-server/ @HermanFransen

Comment: Ok, that's an old project `rfc5766-turn-server`, [last release is july 2015](https://github.com/coturn/rfc5766-turn-server/releases). CoTurn is the successor of this project

Comment: Ok thnx do you know any turn server installation for centos? @HermanFransen

Comment: No sorry, I only have experience with Ubuntu @ClouDarK

Comment: Create a free account here https://global.xirsys.net and test with their turn server, if it works, then there's a problem with your config